# Python C extension: TypeError: argument 1 must be string without null bytes, not str

Tags: python, c

I wrote a Python extension in C and I have a problem. In Python code, I receive data from socket (tcp). The data is a combination of string and struct(written in C).
When I pass the data as arguments to the C extension function, it leads to a `TypeError: argument 1 must be string without null bytes, not str`. What causes the problem?

The code is as follows：
1、Python:

```
def msgProc(self, sockId, data):
    "process incoming msg"
    #may need to rewrite the message lib
    pydecode.decode(data)
```

2、C ：

```
 char *pszData;
 if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &pszData)) {
    printf("param error\n");
    return NULL;
 }
```

Comment: Please post the related code along your question.

Comment: It seems one of the arguments you passed to the C function is a string and contains `'\0'`. Under some circumstances, such `'\0'` will cause trouble.

Comment: Instead of the `char*` string, use a Python object as parameter. Python strings (type `str`) can hold null characters without problem, but C strings (type `char*`) are null-terminated, so they can't contain nulls. BTW: If you pass bytes to the function, then `str` is the wrong type, it should be `bytes` rather. Note also that this assumes a recent version of Python, for the old 2.x versions string handling is a bit different.